# UIImagePickerController AVAudioPlayer

Tags: iphone, ios4, uiimagepickercontroller, avaudioplayer

When I open a `UIImagePickerController`, I can display the device's camera input stream.

But when I play an `AVAudioPlayer` with `[player play]` then the camera stops working.

How can I deal with that?

Comment: Hi, I am having same issue. Please help me if you found any solution.

Comment: Do you open the UIImagePickerController and then try to play audio with AVAudioPlayer?

Answer (score 3):

you can't because UIIMagePickerController is controlling the audio, you will need to use low level AVFoundation in order to do that.

checkout [AVCam](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html) sample code how to record a movie and add the view as subview , that way you will stay in control of the audio and will be able to play audio.