# Capture video/mic on an iPhone while simultaneously outputting sounds to a bluetooth device via AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback mode?

Tags: ios, iphone, audio, bluetooth, avcapturesession

I have an iOS app that outputs sound via an `AVAudioPlayer` to a bluetooth device.  This device does not have a built in microphone. The only way I can get output sound to the device is using the `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback` choice. If I try to use `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord`, I do not get output to the bluetooth device. This has been acceptable until now.

The app now needs to be able to record video (with built in microphone sound) along with outputting premade sounds like before. 
I initially started using `UIImagePickerController` but found it to conflict when playing audio.

Based on this similar question ([UIImagePickerController AVAudioPlayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067084/uiimagepickercontroller-avaudioplayer)), I started to use `AVCaptureSession` instead.

I have set the following for the `AVCaptureSession`:

```
session.automaticallyConfiguresApplicationAudioSession = NO;
session.usesApplicationAudioSession = NO;
```

As long as I do not try to add the built-in mic via `[session addInput:xxx]` the app work fine.
However, when I add the built-in mic the video preview freezes and locks up recording.

I think there is some kind of conflict with using the category `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback`
and trying to add a built-in mic to AVCaptureSession even though I set `usesApplicationAudioSession = NO`

Without this option, my video cannot record the mic sounds onto the video.

Is there a way to capture video/mic on an iPhone while simultaneously outputting sounds to a bluetooth device via `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback` mode?